# Lock Position On Multiple Trigger Enters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Titles sounds confusing but to make it simple... I have two triggers, or "pressure plates" if you will, and they are connected to one door. When both objects are in the trigger, the door raises twice as high. That's the issue, I need the door's transform to stay the same in the case that either one or both triggers are active, but still reset to original position when neither are active. [code for trigger provided below]

If anyone has an idea on this, please let me know.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PadTriggerPlayer1 : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject door;
   public float Height = 0f;
   public bool doorOpened = false;

   void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
   {
       if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player1")
       {
           door.transform.position += new Vector3(0f, Height, 0f);
           doorOpened = true;
       }
   }

   void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
   {
       if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player1")
       {
           door.transform.position += new Vector3(0f, -Height, 0f);
           doorOpened = false;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Rather have a dedicated class with a flag/counter on the door and only do your thing for the first trigger to enter?

Answer (score -1):

Use a counter to know how many triggers are inside:
As if both are inside you need double pressure effect I suggest the height multiplied by the counter `Height * entered`, but up to whatever behaviour you might need.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PadTriggerPlayer1 : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject door;
   public float Height = 0f;
   public bool doorOpened = false;
   private int entered = 0;

   void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
   {
       if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player1")
       {
           entered++;
           door.transform.position += new Vector3(0f, Height * entered, 0f);
           doorOpened = true;
       }
   }

   void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
   {
       if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player1")
       {
           entered--;
           door.transform.position += new Vector3(0f, -Height * entered, 0f);
           doorOpened = false;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Nah, sorry, didn't work. When the trigger was activated, the transform only got locked, and never reset.

Comment: The code is not supposed to work perfectly for your exact case of use, which I do not know. It is not even debugged. It is supposed to give you an idea to handle the status of how many triggers are inside to control how many "pressure plates" do you have activated to handle the status of your door accordingly. You can `Debug.Log` the caunter to track the behaviour of the counter in your game and try to move on. Good luck